# Concat streamed data into single file or string while extracting zip files with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using [yauzl](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl/) node module. I am extracting XML files from Zip file. While reading entries, inside `readSteam.on('data')` callback function, I am logging `entry.filename` and its content as string. However, some files get shredded into multiple files. These parts share same `fileName`. Each part includes part of file content.

```
  let options = {
    lazyEntries: true
  }
  yauzl.open(params.pathToZip, options, function(err, zipfile) {
    if(err) throw err
    zipfile.readEntry()
    zipfile.on("error", function(err) {
      throw err
    })
    zipfile.on("entry", function(entry) {
      if (/\/$/.exec(entry)) return false

      zipfile.openReadStream(entry, options, (err, readStream) => {
        if (err) throw err
        readStream.on('data', data => {
          console.log(entry.fileName)
          console.log(data.toString())
        })
      })
      zipfile.readEntry()
    });
    zipfile.once("end", function() {
      console.log('END EVENT CALLBACK')
      zipfile.close()
    });
  });
```

Is there built-in method that would concat these strings (by knowing that they share same filename) into a single file or string that could be then parsed as one.

Log looks something like this if `substr`) method was used such as `console.log(data.toString().substr(0,10))` (because we only care about 1st few characters of each datafile for representation purposes):

```
TH/CJM/CJM00083_en.xml
<hotel des
TH/CJM/CJM0007V_en.xml
<hotel des
TH/CJM/CJM0007V_en.xml
vel.com/HH
TH/CJM/YYY1RHVV_en.xml
<hotel des
TH/CJM/YYY1RHVV_en.xml
om/hotels/
TH/CJM/YYY0DJJ2_en.xml
<hotel des
TH/CJM/CJM0005P_en.xml
<hotel des
```

As logs show, filenames are repeated when data is shredded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for the `'end'` [event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) to be emitted:

```
zipfile.openReadStream(entry, options, (err, readStream) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  var str = '';
  readStream.on('data', data => {
    str += data.toString();
  });
  readStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log(entry.fileName);
    console.log(str);
    // Next entry...
    zipfile.readEntry();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a plain object or `Map` where property name is file name. If property name exists and is equal to current file name, concatenate text of current file to value of property at object, else create a new property set to current file name, set value of property to file contents; repeat procedure until all files have been processed.

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(fileName)) { obj[fileName] += fileContents } 
else { obj[fileName] = fileContents }
```

Comment: I need to go through ~2 mil files, would this approach cause memory issue?

Comment: @Kunok Not sure what you mean? The approach should not impact memory any more than the process you are currently performing. You would only be sorting the files as the file name is being read.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. But I am not extracting files to filesystem, I want to read them on the fly. Basically, when data is streamed, I want to concat these strings and parse them to json and then save to database.

Comment: @Kunok Are you asking how to predict what the next part of stream will be? _"Basically, when data is streamed, I want to concat these strings and parse them to json and then save to database."_ Yes, that is what approach at Answer describes. `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(filename)) { obj[filename] += fileContents } else { obj[filename] = filename; obj[filename] = filecontents}`

Comment: Yes you are right. Could you  please provide some small code example which represent what answer describes?

Comment: `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(fileName)) { obj[fileName] += fileContents } else { obj[fileName] =  fileContents}`

Comment: Could you add that into your answer?